# Handling batching in new Summer '20 Platform-Event Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, platform-event, bulkification

We are planning to use the new Platform-Event Flows once Summer '20 is released next week, but I have a question around batching.

Currently we use apex triggers to handle platform events. Those can receive a batch of up to 2000 events, and we need to follow standard bulkification practices to handle those.

Do the new Platform-Event Flows need to consider this batching? Or are they truly able to operate on 1 record at a time? That seems like it can't possibly be true, but I can't find any documentation on these new flows anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flows are [automatically bulkified](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_concepts_bulkification.htm) by the runtime. There are some caveats, because flows do execute one record at a time, but they pause when they reach a DML or Query operation, then perform all actions for each point reached. Note that Decision nodes can cause some flows to skip a step, and that's okay, the system is smart enough to delay those until the remainder catch up. That is to say, assuming your flows are written in an efficient manner (e.g. don't put a Fast Update in a Loop), it will work properly with this new feature.

Comment: Awesome, and thank you for the link

Comment: Given that you mentioned up to 2000 records though, I'm not sure that bulkification link covers the [2000 execution limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_considerations_limit.htm&type=5) flow also has. How this is calculated has been a source of discussion at times.